# Oracle: Listener alias vs Listener name

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, listener

In sqlplus we can set the local_listener to either the description of the listener or the listener alias. What is the difference between listener alias and listener name. Are these the same ? If not how can I resolve the listener name from the listener alias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listener alias and Listener name need not be the same. The database resolves the listener alias to the correct listener description by looking up the `tnsnames.ora` file.